# How can I make an element take up full screen height with scrolling?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap on my website and I want to make the element with class `jumbotron` take up the full user window. Then the user can scroll through the rest of the site.

Currently, I have it working with:

**CSS:**

```
jumbotron { height: 100vh;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="jumbotron">
     ...
    </div>  
</div>

... rest of site ...
```

but I want to fool-proof my site to make it as reliable as possible and want to use a more widely accepted way.

Comment: "Fool-proof my site" - What is wrong with `100vh`?  Is there a specific browser you are concerned with?

Comment: I was told vh sits at about 70% compatibility, I am not convinced that's good enough since it will be viewed by all kinds of comps

Comment: Intrinsic measuring units like vh and vw are more like 90%. Aside from some edge cases involving IE, Edge, & iOS, vh and vw are good to go. [Reference](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: I'd recommend using something like caniuse.com or similar to determine if the compatibility meets your requirement.  It's a great unit, and doing the 100% height thing to all parent containers *always causes problems* when I've used it in projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `container-flud`
before the `jumbotron` `class` 
For full screen height make a class and give style Like `.fullS_height {height: 100vh;}`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-flud">
  <div class="jumbotron fullS_height">
    <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>
    <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
  </div>
  <p>This is some text.</p>
  <p>This is another text.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fullS_height {
  height: 100vh;
  }
```

```css
.fullS_height {
  height: 100vh;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-flud">
  <div class="jumbotron fullS_height">
    <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>
    <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
  </div>
  <p>This is some text.</p>
  <p>This is another text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: sure I am going to make it just a moment .

Comment: @user3550879 right Now height is full screen, So is it right ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to give every parent of `jumbotron` up to `html` CSS property `height:100%`;

**Example**

```css
html, body, .container, .row, .jumbotron {
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="jumbotron">
             ...
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Bear in mind **it will work only for elements right after `<body>` tag**.

Comment: wont that not make the site scrollable? And it will wreck any future use of those features (.row and .container are used in bootstrap framework on different pages)

Comment: This answer is **not** accurate.

Comment: And why do you say so? I'm looking for working example, will have it in one sec

Comment: Here you are:
http://mdbootstrap.com/wp-content/themes/mdbootstrap4/Tutorials/bootstrap/IV-7/index.html

Comment: Of course it answers only the height aspect, width is another story.

Comment: It's not accurate in the choice of words - `need to do`.  There's other, better options.  And the OP's original `vh` method is perfectly legit.